# How to put variable in img src link

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have 2 variables: Latitude and Longitude:
   I want to insert it like this.

`<img src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=15&size=640x640&scale=2&key=example";`
Here's my code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function TestGeo() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( TestMap, error, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false} );
      } else {
          alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
            }
        function TestMap(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;}
        </script>

        </head>
        <body onload="TestGeo();">
        <img src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=15&size=640x640&scale=2&key=example";
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I don't know which one to use. What do you suggest? Please advice.

Comment: Both language are doable. Where will you need this? frontend or backend server parsing?

Comment: Would help if you were a lot more specific about how you expect this to work within your app

Comment: I am going to make a webapp. About clock in and clockout. When person walks into the area of the set location. It will clock in that user in to the server side with timestamp and will return the result as "OK" or "Falied".

Comment: `<img src="dummy.gif" id="where" />` then have `document.getElementById(where").src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
center="+latitude+","+longitude+"&zoom=15&size=640x640&scale=2&key=example";`

Comment: @mplungjan not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript . try this

```
            function TestMap(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var imgsrc = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"&zoom=15&size=640x640&scale=2&key=example";
            $('#imgselector').attr('src', imgsrc)
            }
```

html should be 
`<img src="" id="imgselector"/>`

Comment: Not tagged jQueru and concatenation is identical to my comment

Comment: @mplungjan  I put it in my code but the map does not showing